# how can i use provider solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a comment page with a sort button. I use two ChangeNotifier CommentModel and SortTypeModel, how can I combine these two models?

```
class CommentListModel with ChangeNotifier{
  List<String> commentList = [];

  bool revert = false;

  loadComment(){
    // do something
  }
}

class SortTypeModel with ChangeNotifier{
  bool revert = false;
}
```

Comment: What is `revert` meant to do in `CommentListModel`? And what does `revert` in `SortTypeModle` do?

Comment: just like comment, revert=true means from near to far,revert=false means far to near.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to do. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want these classes to become one class? Or do you want to use these classes to be used at the same time in a different part of your code?